# Databinding to a Parent datacontext in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

The user control into which those 2 elements live has a property called ColumnTypes.

Each of those elements refer relatively with the same expression to the main datacontext, yet the first one does **not** work, while the latter does.

Do you have any idea how to investigate that ?

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="Type"   >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.GetColumnTypes"   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Path="DataContext.GetColumnTypes"   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.GetColumnTypes; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=53813616); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

You can see [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) what kind of things you can bind to its `ItemsSource` property. A regular property is not one of them, so your case wont work.

A different way to achieve what you want, is to make a `DataGridTemplateColumn` which contains a `ComboBox`.

In your case that would look something like this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.GetColumnTypes, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I remained very puzzled by the unpredictability, from my profane pov, of such a thing. is it really common knowledge of wpf devs ? are there many things such as that ?

Comment: Glad it helped. There are some things that work a bit weird in WPF, yes. Usually good answers can be found on Stackoverflow though. It definitely is a very different from Winforms.

Answer (score 3):

`DataGridColumn` not lies in the `Visual Tree` of DataGrid hence it `can't inherit its DataContext`. But there are workarounds for it i.e. you can explicitly supply DataContext to your DataGridColumns whose details can be found [Provide DataContext to DataGrid Columns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx).

Also, i personally like approach described here - [Inheriting parent DataContext using Freezable](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) of inheriting using `Freezable` class.

Code from `first link` in case link does not work in future -

Add this in your `App.xaml.cs in App() constructor` -

```
FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DataGridColumn));
FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty.OverrideMetadata ( typeof(DataGrid),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata 
   (null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, 
   new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDataContextChanged)));
```

The OnDataContextChanged callback simply forwards the DataContext from DataGrid to its columns:

```
public static void OnDataContextChanged ( DependencyObject d, 
                                          DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    DataGrid grid = d as DataGrid ; 
    if ( grid != null  ) 
    {                 
        foreach ( DataGridColumn col in grid.Columns ) 
        { 
            col.SetValue ( FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty,  e.NewValue ); 
        } 
    } 
}
```